# Data upload from Visual Studio to SQL Server Timeout

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a big Problem sending an SQL-Dump made with SQL-Server Management Studio via vb.net to another SQL-Server. 
I made the SQL-Files like this: Database / Tasks / scripts ...

After deleting every "GO" command in the Dump I managed to upload to my local SQL-Server 2012. But this worked only if I made different scripts for any table.
If I use one big File, I get a timeout.

Now I want to transfer the Data (50 MB) to another SQL Server via Internet connection. 
Only 3 of 5 Tables are generated on this server :-(

I get the following timeout error (german version, sorry):

"Eine Ausnahme (erste Chance) des Typs "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" ist in System.Data.dll aufgetreten.
Timeout abgelaufen. Das Zeitlimit wurde vor dem Beenden des Vorgangs überschritten oder der Server reagiert nicht."

Any Idea which side makes the timeout (SQL-Server oder vb.net)?
Is there a safer method uploading lots of data to a SQL-Server?

This is the code I use (The SQL-Skript is in My.Resources.SQLDump):

```
    '####SQLDump  #######
    Dim SQLscript As String = My.Resources.SQLDump


    SQLscript = "USE [" + TextBoxDB.Text + "] " + vbCrLf + SQLscript


    Using connection As New SqlConnection(Verbind.ConStr)

        Using command As New SqlCommand()
            ' Set the connection
            command.Connection = connection

            ' Not necessary, but good practice
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            ' Example query using parameters
            command.CommandText = SQLscript

            Try
                connection.Open()
                rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception

                Debug.Print(ex.Message)
            Finally
                command.Dispose()
                connection.Dispose()
            End Try
            'command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using ' Dispose Command

    End Using ' Dispose (and hence Close) Connection

    MsgBox("DB-Upload 1/5 fertig!")
```

Comment: What you are doing a form of ETL.  You will find several threads on this site stating why you should do ETL using ETL tools, rather than write a script.

Comment: I never did ETL before and both servers are only available in different LAN.
So I dump the data here and my program running in a different LAN will update the data there.

kbkb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a safer method uploading lots of data to a SQL-Server?

Yes, there are couple of ways to load data into SQL Server

1. [bcp Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx)
2. [BULK INSERT statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx)
3. [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx)
4. [SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx)

> Important note: On a 64-bit computer, Integration Services installs
>   the 64-bit version of the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
>   (DTSWizard.exe). However, some data sources, such as Access or Excel,
>   only have a 32-bit provider available. To work with these data
>   sources, you might have to install and run the 32-bit version of the
>   wizard. To install the 32-bit version of the wizard, select either
>   Client Tools or SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) during setup.

5. [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services)

   [Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx) to create a SSIS package

Being a SSIS developer I can go in deep and demostrate possible ways to import data by using SSIS like

- Bulk import
- Script task
- Flat file source/ Excel source
- Etc Etc.. but that would be different from the question which you have asked.

Regarding, resolving your error you can set the [command timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) property in your code to make it run for any specific time limit or limitless.

> command.CommandTimeout = 1;
>
> Note: The CommandTimeout property will be ignored during asynchronous
>   method calls such as BeginExecuteReader.

**Edited**
Here is the sample code

```
Using command As New SqlCommand()
        command.Connection = connection
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        command.CommandText = SQLscript
        command.CommandTimeout = 1
        Try
            connection.Open()
            rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.Message)
        Finally
            command.Dispose()
            connection.Dispose()
        End Try
End Using
```

Other way is to extend [connection timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) in your [connection string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx). It accept integer which indicates seconds (in below example connection timeout is set to 30 seconds; 0 means unlimited)

> Connection Timeout=30;

Comment: Wow, a bunch of alternatives...
Because my Program has never access to both servers (different LAN), the SQL-Export / Import wizard will not work for me.
So bcp or bulk insert seems to be an alternative.

But first I try the commandTimeout. But I do not know where to place the command. Does anyone has an example?

In Declaration I have to do this, right?
"Public Overrides Property CommandTimeout As Integer"

I found somewhere that connection timeout is only used for login.

kbhb@gmx.net

Comment: @Kbhb I have updated my answer. Sorry for the delay, I wasn't feeling good yesterday.

Comment: Thank You for the example.
I increased the commandTimeout and now 2 of 3 servers work.
:-)

Answer (score 0):

**Import / Export Wizard for one time move**

Since you were able to generate scripts, you have access to the source.  Since you're able to execute them, you have access to the destination, and you have Management Studio installed.  Your fastest option, IMO, is the Import Export utility provided by Sql Server.

In Sql Server Management Studio, right click on the source database name, click on "Tasks" and then click on "Export Data".  This opens up a wizard that will let you put in Source, Destination, and pick the objects you want to export.

While 50 MB of scripts is large, 50MB of data move should finish within a matter of minutes.

**Moving data over and over again**

You have several options, I would go with `OpenRowset`, especially for the size of data you're moving.  Here's a reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

If you go into moving Gigabytes worth of data regularly, then SSIS packages are your best option. Here's a tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx

Comment: Sorry, the rest of my comment was not saved because of a timeout here. What a coincidence ;-)

Open Rowset seems to be SQL-Server to SQL-Server with T-SQL.
There is no direct connection possible because of different LAN.
My Program comes with the data inside and pushes them into the new database

greetings kbhb

Comment: Does that mean that you're running two separate programs on two separate lans?

Comment: No, I make the dump here and compile the program here.
After sending it to the destination, it uses an update feature to get a new version including the bundled resources (SQLDump.txt-files)
The Program offers the possibility to init the DB (drop tablbles, create new, insert data) if necessary.
So I can change this and that including database changes and